# Remove string with wildcard in Notepad++

Tags: json, regex, notepad++, wildcard

I'm trying to merge multiple JSON data sets into one large data set, due to a max limit of 100 on the server I'm pulling them from.

The easiest way to do this would be to eliminate the end of one set and the beginning of the next and replace it with "," so that there would be only one open and close to the entire large set. This is what appears between the last entry of one set and the first entry of the next currently:

```
],"version":"1.0"}{"error":"OK","limit":100,"offset":100,"number_of_page_results":100,
"number_of_total_results":20235,"status_code":1,"results":[
```

Again, I need that entire string replaced with just a comma, but the problem I'm encountering is that I had to change the offset between each data set to grab the next 100 entries, so the "offset":100, is different in each string ("offset":200, "offset":300, etc.). I can't seem to get wildcards to cooperate. I suspect it has something to do with all the brackets that are already in the string.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add what you want to see?

Comment: As stated, I just want to see a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression that matches the whole input you provided (provided there's no new line characters) is:

```
\],"version":"1\.0"\}\{"error":"OK","limit":[0-9]+,"offset":[0-9]+,"number_of_page_results":[0-9]+,"number_of_total_results":[0-9]+,"status_code":[0-9]+,"results":\[
```

It will get any digits in place off all the numbers in your sample (except version).

Comment: Find is also saying it's an invalid regular expression.

Comment: @Chird Forgot to escape curly braces, check it now.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!